# paper-dropdown-menu / paper-listbox : how to get the value in the request

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-elements

I have paper-listbox elemnt in a paper-dropdown-menu, values of items are different from labels.
Here is the example

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Gender" name="gender" required error-message="Gender is required">
   <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" attr-or-property-name="value">
      <paper-item value="M">Male</paper-item>
      <paper-item value="F">Female</paper-item>
   </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

But in the post, the label is given instead of the value of the item

Any idea to have `gender=M` or `gender=F` in the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, though you have to add an `id` attribute to the `paper-listbox` and dig a bit:

```
<dom-module id="item-value-demo">
  <template>
    <style></style>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Gender" name="gender" required error-message="Gender is required">
      <paper-listbox id="gender" slot="dropdown-content" attr-or-property-name="value">
         <paper-item value="M">Male</paper-item>
         <paper-item value="F">Female</paper-item>
      </paper-listbox>
   </paper-dropdown-menu>
  </template>
  <script>
    class ItemValueDemo extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'item-value-demo'; }

      ready() {
        super.ready();
        this.$.gender.addEventListener('selected-item-changed', e => { this._genderOption(e) });
      }

      _genderOption(e) {
        const value = e.target.selectedItem;
        if (value) {
          console.log(value.attributes["value"].value);
        }
      }
    }
    customElements.define(ItemValueDemo.is, ItemValueDemo);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<item-value-demo></item-value-demo>
```

See [this pen](https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/EoOzqB).

Comment: There is second issue.  "attr-or-property-name=" should be "attr-for-selected=" to make this work.